# Access JSON attributes from django template

Tags: python, django, json, templates, django-templates

I am trying to access JSON attributes through django template. 
I can access to the name of the attribute but not the value.
Here is what I do:

view:

```
      def view(request):
        b= {u'1': u'xxxxx', u'2': u'yyyyy'}
        a=json.loads(b)
```

template:

```
 {% for val in a %}
    {{ val }}
```

the result I see is: 1 2

I want to display xxxxx and yyyyy

(when I write {{ val.1 }} I get nothing)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
{% for k, v in a.items %}
    {{ v }}
{% endfor %}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#for